# All My Chromium Web Browser extensions are gone

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

I am running Ubuntu (Lucid) and had a problem booting up the OS after a recent set of updates. I took the "easy route" and held down the shift key during boot up and chose one of the previous kernels.

That successfully got me back into my OS, Libre Office is working fine, and all of the folders in my Home Directory seem to be intact. However when I opened up "Chromium Web Browser" (a derivative from Chrome), all of my surfing history and more importantly all of my extensions, are gone.

Any tips on how I can verify that the directories storing this information are still there and how to restore all of that provided that the information is still physically on my hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me; I put safeguards in place to protect myself and then I forget that I had put them into place.

All I had to do was go to the "Personal Stuff" area in Chromium and sign in. I had already set it up a couple years ago http://goo.gl/IIXh (now I remember) so that all of my extensions and settings were synchronized in my Google Account.

That was "a life safer" :-)